# 'decorator is not a function' error when angular1, angular2 & angular_1_router used together

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I'm using angular1, angular_1_router and angular2 in the same application. When I run the app, I get the error **decorator is not a function**. The image of the error is shown below.

```
    <script src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.46/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/angular_1_router.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a hacky solution right now, rather not need to muck about with source files. But, from [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5292), if you change

```
var exports = {Injectable: function () {}};
```

to

```
var exports = {Injectable: function () {
  return (function(target) {
    return target;
  });
}};
```

It should work and stop giving you that error - worked for me. Hopefully it will be fixed properly soon.